# How to join aspnet_membership and aspnet_users using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, join

I'm having a hard time to figure out how to join aspnet tables using LINQ .
So here's my inquiries.

> How to Join these aspnet tables or how to get the exact column name or data of these aspnet tables using LINQ/MVC 3. aspnet_Membership, aspnet_Users , aspnet_UsersInRoles and aspnet_Roles .

Once I get the values or their column names I'll be joining them in my two other tables in different database.

here's my code in sqlserver which I want to convert into LINQ statement.

```
SELECT AU.UserId,
       AU.UserName,
       ( MNTP.LastName + ',' + MNTP.FirstName + ' '
         + LEFT(MNTP.MiddleName, 1) + '.' ) Name,
       AR.RoleName
FROM   aspnetdb..aspnet_Membership AM
       INNER JOIN aspnetdb..aspnet_Users AU
               ON AM.UserId = AU.UserId
       INNER JOIN aspnetdb..aspnet_UsersInRoles AUR
               ON AU.UserId = AUR.UserId
       INNER JOIN aspnetdb..aspnet_Roles AR
               ON AUR.RoleId = AR.RoleId
       INNER JOIN User_ManagementDB..MNT_Users MNTU
               ON AU.UserId = MNTU.aspnet_UsersID
       INNER JOIN User_ManagementDB..MNT_Person MNTP
               ON MNTU.PersonID = MNTP.ID
```

And here's my code in trying to convert it into LINQ statement:

```
var _rolesRepo = new RolesRepository();
var _users = LoadAll();// Um_MNT_Users
var _person = entities.People.ToList();// UM_Person
var _role = _rolesRepo.LoadAll(); 

var _userMem = Membership.GetAllUsers()
        .Cast<MembershipUser>()
        .Select(m => m).ToList(); // I dont know if this is the right syntax to get the aspnet_membership.

var _query = from user in _users
             join personID in _person on user.PersonID equals personID.ID
```

Please help me guys.

Comment: Guys please help me with this! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't see the question being tagged with `Entity Framework` I assume you can't create a stored procedure with that logic and call it whenever you need the results...

If all your data is in memory you can use this query:

```
var result = AspMemmership // the collection of data from aspnetdb..aspnet_Membership table
    .Join(AspUsers,        // the collection of data from aspnetdb..aspnet_Users table
        m => m.UserId,
        u => u.UserId,
        (m, u) => u)
    .Join(AspUsersInRoles,
        u => u.UserId,
        ur => ur.UserId,
        (u, ur) => new
        {
            u.UserId,
            u.UserName,
            ur.RoleId
        })
    .Join(AspRoles,
        x => x.RoleId,
        r => r.RoleId,
        (x, r) => new
        {
            x.UserId,
            x.UserName,
            r.RoleName
        })
    .Join(MNT_Users,
        x => x.UserId,
        u => u.aspnet_UsersID,
        (x, u) => new
        {
            x.UserId,
            x.UserName,
            u.PersonId,
            r.RoleName
        })
    .Join(MNT_Persons,
        x => x.PersonId,
        p => p.Id,
        (x, p) => new
        {
            x.UserId,
            x.UserName,
            u.PersonId,
            Name = String.Format("{0},{1} {2}.", 
                p.LastName, p.FirstName, p.MiddleName.Substring(0, 1)),
            r.RoleName
        })
```

Comment: Oh Thank you so much for this @RePierre. :) I have last question., how would I get the list of Aspnet_membership and aspnet_users separately?  and aspnet_usersinrole also., thank you!

Comment: @user1395586, you just load them from database as you do with `MNT_Persons` if you have access to database. Otherwise, you can use `GetAllUsers` method from the `MembershipProvider` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.getallusers(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: is that for both aspnet_membership and aspnet_users or for aspnet_membership only??

Comment: @JanMichael `GetAllUsers` is for `aspnet_users`. For roles, refer to `RoleProvider` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: ohh that's such a big help! Is this code for aspnet_membership? Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>().Select(m => m).ToList() ? and do you think this is the right way to join it in my MNT_users? join name in _userMem on user.aspnet_UsersID equals name.ProviderUserKey?? Thankyou so much for your time! you are such a big help ! indeed!

Comment: oh thank you! :) I'm trying not to use Stored Procedure for this., I hope this time my join statement in LINQ would work already. Thank you again. :)